# how can I write a script to move relative cursor position with a keystroke (Like AHK on Windows)

Tags: command-line, scripts, mouse, cursor

An example in [AHK](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/MouseMove.htm) would be:

> 1::Click, right
>
> 2::MouseMove, 0, 70, 0, R
>
> 3::Click

Answer (score 4):

Install [xdotool](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/man1/xdotool.1.html):

```
sudo apt-get install xdotool
```

and from a terminal or script:

- Up

  ```
  xdotool mousemove_relative -- 0 -70
  ```
- Down

  ```
  xdotool mousemove_relative 0 70
  ```
- Right

  ```
  xdotool mousemove_relative 70 0
  ```
- Left

  ```
  xdotool mousemove_relative -- -70 0
  ```

You can also pilot clicks with:

- Left click

  ```
  xdotool click 1
  ```
- Right click

  ```
  xdotool click 3
  ```

Comment: Silly, but I never discovered  `mousemove_relative`. I always calculated form `xdotool getmouselocation`. This is much better :)